# Fastest way to calculate Prime

Tags: c#, performance, primes

I'm trying to Implement types of primes in my program. In one of the type Exponent Of Mersenne, the formula to calculate is `(2 power P) -1` Here `P is Prime.` and check the output is prime.

In calculating, I'm able to get the power but while checking for prime, the process is Hanging . and if I leave it for a very long long time then it is being calculated.

example would be, (2 power 10090) -1 and calculate if this is prime

I'm using Big Integer

I'musing this code

```
int prime1 = CalculatePrime(n);
BigInteger powerPrime = BigInteger.Pow(2, prime1);
bool isPrime = CheckPrime(powerPrime - 1);

private bool CheckPrime(BigInteger num)
{
    if (num == 0 || num == 1) 
        return false;

    bool isPrime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j < num; j++)
    {
        if ((num % j) == 0)
        {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```

How would be this - http://www.dotnetperls.com/prime

Comment: Are you sure it's hanging and not just taking a very long time?  This is a particularly poor algorithm for finding primes, so being as slow as it is it will take a *very* long time for all but the most trivial input values.

Comment: for starters, you can do `j < (num/2)`

Comment: Its taking a very long time.

Comment: The list of related questions shows quite a few questions on the topic of calculating primes. I’d suggest you to start there.

Comment: Google/wikipedia are also good resources.

Comment: [This](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=math_for_topcoders) should help. It's an algorithm that should be faster than what you have, as well as text to help you understand the code.

Comment: You: _(2 power 10090) -1 and calculate if this is prime_ Bad example. Since `10090` is even, `2**10090 - 1` is divisible by three (`3`).

Comment: ok then take this 2**13466917 - 1 This is a prime.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the noted question. That was asking about numbers in general, this is asking specifically about Mersenne numbers of the form 2**k-1.

Comment: Instead of throwing around big numbers like 2**13466917-1, how about using 2*89-1, which is prime, as an example. It's easier than working with those big numbers, but still sufficient to address the question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a particularly good algorithm for generating prime numbers that are less than a few million.

Comment: `2^10090 - 1` is a lot bigger than “a few million” though… ^^

Comment: @poke He edited in those numbers later, but yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The [Lucas-Lehmer test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) is specialized for checking whether Mersenne numbers are prime. You should use it in preference to the test you have implemented, which as you noticed can be very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a bit less work to do because of following:

1. You have to check only for `j < sqrt(num)`, not `j < num`
2. You don't have to check every even number: just try with 2 at the beginning and then check only odd numbers (that's because every even number can be divided by 2, so if x cannot be divided by 2 it cannot be divided by any other even number)

Comment: While this can help a bit, the general algorithm is just so poor that it just won't scale at all to very large numbers.

Comment: You've got even and odd mixed up.